# Get the mysql table Row content and Inser it into the Same Table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Here i have situation in my mysql table,i want get the particular row value and the same value i want to insert into another row in the same table.

Here the example

```
qualification Name Age id(pk)
BE            ragu 22 1
BE            ravi 33 2
```

I want To insert 2nd row again,the result must b like the following:

```
qualification Name Age id(pk)
BE            ragu 22 1
BE            ravi 33 2
BE            ravi 33 3
```

Suggest me some idea.... thanks in advance...

Comment: I have a bolt that needs to be tightened.

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax for that

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 (qualification, Name, Age, id)
SELECT qualification, Name, Age, 3
  FROM Table1
 WHERE id = 2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f827b/1)** demo